# How to determine which control was touched?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, uipickerview

I have two PickerViews in my view, how do I set my delegates to identify which one to handle?
Some kind of `if()` to validate if the picker that threw the event was the pickerX or pickerY?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have IBOUtlets for the PickerViews like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *firstPickerView; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *secondPickerView;
```

and then in a delegate method do something like this

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component {
  if (pickerView == self.firstPickerView) {
  }
  else if (pickerView == self.secondPickerView) {
  }
}
```

or you can set tags on the PickerViews in IB and do

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component {
  if (pickerView.tag == 0) {

  }
  else if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't know about the first option, that's also a good one. I used the second, though, with the TAG id's. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When any delegate method is called, it also pass the object on which it is called, lets say in this case.

```
– pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:
```

You can identify the particular picker by its TAG id. And yah if else will be used.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful tip. Used `thePickerView.tag` and got what I wanted.